# what is the use of standardUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am new in iphone programming. please explain me this code. and that is the use of standardUserDefaults? how this code will work?

```
-(void)load
  {
DLog("Load Configuration");

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

bool savedDefaults = [defaults boolForKey:kKeySavedDefaults];
if (savedDefaults)
{
    columns = [defaults integerForKey:kKeyColumns];
    if (columns == 0) columns = kColumnsDefault;

    rows = [defaults integerForKey:kKeyRows];
    if (rows == 0) rows = kRowsDefault;

    photoType = [defaults integerForKey:kKeylastPhotoType];
    photoEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:kKeyPhotoEnabled];
    numbersEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:kKeyNumbersEnabled];
    soundEnabled = [defaults boolForKey:kKeySoundEnabled];
}
else
{
    columns = kColumnsDefault;
    rows = kRowsDefault;
    photoType = klastPhotoTypeDefault;
    photoEnabled = kPhotoEnabledDefault;
    numbersEnabled = kNumbersEnabledDefault;
    soundEnabled = kSoundEnabledDefault;
}
}
-(void)save
    {
    DLog("Save Configuration");
    BOOL restart = NO;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults integerForKey:kKeyColumns] != columns) { restart = YES; }
    if ([defaults integerForKey:kKeyRows] != rows) { restart = YES; }

    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:kKeySavedDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:columns forKey:kKeyColumns];
    [defaults setInteger:rows forKey:kKeyRows];
    [defaults setInteger:photoType forKey:kKeylastPhotoType];
    [defaults setBool:photoEnabled forKey:kKeyPhotoEnabled];
    [defaults setBool:numbersEnabled forKey:kKeyNumbersEnabled];
    [defaults setBool:soundEnabled forKey:kKeySoundEnabled];
    [defaults synchronize];

     [board configChanged:restart];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

User defaults are used to store little configuration parameters.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for
>   interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an
>   application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences.
>   For example, you can allow users to determine what units of
>   measurement your application displays or how often documents are
>   automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning
>   values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The
>   parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to
>   determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts
>   by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some small amount of data like username,password...... by using these concept you can store the values

Comment: My password in an plain and open plist?! I just hope that I don't use one of your apps oO

Comment: Better use the keychain for passwords.